# Can you extract data from an Excel Workbook using Azure Data Factory that has Azure Information Protection

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-information-protection

I have an internal document (Excel) that has an Azure information Protection / O365 Unified Sensitivity Labelling applied to it.

Im trying to extract that data, but I'm getting an Encryption Error because and rightly so the information is encrypted.

**The process:**
The document is pulled from Sharepoint into a blob storage container and then Azure Data factory picks up the file using the Copy activity and reads the contents into an Azure SQL Database

Error message:
ErrorCode=EncryptedExcelIsNotSupported,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Encrypted excel file 'dummy file.xlsx' is not supported, please remove its password.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipException,Message=Wrong Local header signature: 0xE011CFD0,Source=ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib,'

I have a Linked Service using a Service principal that can connect to the file, but previewing the data results in a message saying the file is encrypted.

I presume I would need to give permissions to the Service Principal, but im still stuck what those would be.
I tried adding Azure Rights Management read/create in the API permissions but that still hasn't worked

Answer (score 0):

Data Factory can't read the file data which is protected by other service.

If you want to copy data from the encrypted files, you must have the permission to access it.

Comment: Where and how would you go about granting the permission?
There is no Permission on the ADF CopyActivity ?

Comment: @Neuromancer As I said, Data Factory can't read the file data which is protected by other service.  The permission is related in linked service. For example, you must has the permission to access the blob storage if you want to cope the data in the container.

Comment: Yeah I updated my post earlier today, I've got as far as playing with the service principal that accesses the storage account, and it smells like giving the service account Azure Right Management Permissions should work but its still not working.

My assumption is that I should be providing an account to the service principal that can impersonate as a user that has permissions to read thee encrypted document, so im kinda struggling there.

Comment: @Neuromancer  the encrypted file is not support. Ref this feedback: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/10212129-support-encrypted-flat-files-as-the-source-in-copy

Comment: @Neuromancer If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.